# Как достичь единообразного отображения сайта во всех браузерах?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, internet-explorer, dreamweaver, браузер

Написал страницу сайта в Dreamweaver со следующим содержанием:

```
<?php include('blocks/header.php'); ?>
<div style="width:700px; margin:0 auto; border:#000 thin solid">
<div style="width:290px; float:left; border:#000 thin solid">
<!--категории-->
&nbsp;

</div><!--категории-->
<div style="width:400px; float:right; border:#000 thin solid"><!--ввод каатегорий--><form method="post" action="save_cat.php">
<label>Новая категория</label><br />
<input name="name_cat" type="text" size="40" />
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="добавить категорию" />

</form>
</div><!--ввод каатегорий-->
</div>

<?php include('blocks/footer.php'); ?>
```

Привожу `blocks/header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Главная страница админ зоны сайта</title>
</head>

<body style="margin-top:-20px; margin-left:0; font-family:'Comic Sans MS', cursive">
<div style="background-color:#93F"><!--header-->
<h1 style="padding-top:15px; padding-left:20px">Создаем интернет магазин на PHP</h1>

</div><!--header-->
```

и `blocks/footer.php`:

```
<div style="clear:both; background-color:#93F"><!--footer-->
<h4 style="text-align:center">Автор: Сергей Кудренко</h4>

</div><!--footer-->

</body>
</html>
```

Эта страница отображается нормально в `Chrome` (проверил запустив непосредственно из dreamweaver):

[image]

(на рисунке не видно, но блоки, созданные div-ами, во одном из которых добавляется категория, находятся на одинаковом расстоянии от краев страницы).
А в `IE` отображается неверно (проверил запустив непосредственно из dreamweaver):

[image]

как видно левый блок прижат к левому краю страницы и отображается несколько по-другому.
Возможно ли достичь единообразного отображения сайта во всех браузерах и если можно, то как?

Comment: Dreamweaver ... как давно я не слышал этого слова...

Comment: Я бы посоветовал Frontpage express 97

Answer (score 1):

Ты присваиваешь margin 0 auto только одному диву. Помести их в общий див с этим свойством.